# How to make a line-graph with the x-axis being date on vba-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in excel that is sorted by people, date, and hours.  I need to make a line graph with the x-axis being time and y-axis being hours, and add several line graphs depending on department. I know which people are in what department, but I don't know how to make a line graph with x-axis being time.

Comment: Use a scatter plot, not a line graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you format the data as dates it may do it automatically.

Otherwise you can set the [category type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839414.aspx) property to `xlTimeScale`